# Show interfaces brief information

Tags: cisco, packet-tracer, cli

In packet tracer if you hover over a router you will see its interfaces with IP addresses, vlans, etc. However during my CCNA exams (during the troubleshooting) this feature is disabled. Is there a command in the CLI that shows this information?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most common commands are

```
show interfaces
show ip interface brief
```

Or for a specific interface

```
show interfaces vlan 1
```

Comment: Yes thanks this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Glad to help.  If you accept an answer, click on the check mark or the answer becomes an undead zombie, and will come around every few months hoping to be resolved.

Comment: Yes thanks I'm just waiting till I am able to.